# Making X work with new GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I recently upgraded my GPU, from 1060 6GB to 3080ti. I tried to boot my Ubuntu 20.10 installation, which has my old GPU's drivers installed, but X doesn't want to startup properly, as the server crashes on the start. I managed to get into TTY, replaced the drivers with new ones by using the `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` PPA and downloading the `nvidia-450` package. I can now boot my Ubuntu to my login screen, though my input devices are not working anymore, neither mouse nor keyboard. I tried reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-all` package, but that didn't resolve the issue at all. I also wiped xorg.conf.d config file(s).

The question is, what's happening and what do I do to solve my problem?

Comment: Why use the 450 driver? Much later ones like 465 are available in the standard repositories, and should be tried first. Maybe even the 470 would be available from the graphics-drivers PPA.

Comment: Pre-caution, I feel like older drivers are more stable than the newer ones.

Comment: With the latest hardware, like your 3080ti, try the latest drivers and kernel. Ubuntnu 21.04 and the 465 driver would be the starting point. Alpha/Beta releases with later kernels and graphics-drivers PPA later drivers would be the next step within the Ubuntu community. Latest (non-Ubuntu) kernels, Nvidia drivers from Nvidia are the last resort.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling the OS. Time was almost up 'till I had to do some work, so yeah. Thanks, anyway.